# Proving a sequence converges almost surely given some conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables
>   for which $E(X_i) = 0$ and $E(X_i^2) = V < \infty$. Prove that for any
>   $\gamma> 1/2$, the series $\sum_{i\geq 1} X_i/i^{\gamma}$ converges
>   almost surely.

I am not so sure how to approach this problem, and I would really appreciate your help. I have the following Theorem which may be useful:

> Three Series Theorem: Let $X_{i}$ be a sequence of independent random
>   variables. If for some $c > 0$ each of the three series converges,
>   then the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_{i}$ converges almost surely.
>
> 1) $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} E(X_i^{c})$
>
> 2) $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \text{Var}(X_i^{c})$
>
> 3) $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(|X_i| \geq c)$

But I have tried with this theorem for long with no luck. I would greatly appreciate your help in solving this problem

Comment: You should replace $X_i$ by $\frac {X_i} {i^{\gamma}}$ in the three conditions. You could make a start by trying to prove 3) using Chebyshev 's inequality.

Comment: @Kabo Murphy Do I use $c = 1$?

Comment: Yes, you can take $c=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using the two series theorem : If $Y_n$ is a sequence of independent random variables such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E[Y_n]$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty Var[Y_n]$ are both finite, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty Y_n$ converges almost surely.

In our case, $Y_n = \frac{X_n}{n^\gamma}$. We have $E[Y_n] = 0$ so the sum is of course convergent,  and $Var[Y_n] = \frac{V}{n^{2 \gamma}}$. But since $\gamma > \frac 12$ we have $2 \gamma > 1$ so $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{V}{i^{2 \gamma}} < \infty$. Therefore the variance sum is also finite.

Now the result follows. Note that identically distributed was not required. Also, Kolmogorov's two series theorem is usually discussed before the three series theorem, which is the one you have referred to in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the two-series theorem and I am doing this problem to study for an exam (so I think it is best that I learn it the three-series way). From what it seems, I just also need to show condition (3) from here?

Comment: I am sure you can modify this argument, take $c = 1$ and try it?

Comment: Just want to clarify --- I think your argument makes conditions (1) and (2) true for $c = 1$ in the three-series theorem, right? So I just need to show condition (3) with $c = 1$?

Comment: No, the definition of $X_n^c$ is *not* $X_n$ *to the power of* $c$ : actually, it stands for the random variable $X^c_n = X_n 1_{|X_n| \geq c}$ : that is, this random variable equals $X_n$ if $|X_n| \geq c$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: By the way, turns out you were right. The book did teach two-series theorem first

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance, and also I think it was logical that the two series theorem appear before the three series one.